# Jhipster Ionic entity creation : no such file _entity.html.ejs

Tags: ionic-framework, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster and i'm trying to make my application with Jhipster-Ionic. And i'm stuck with the entity part.

I have created the backend and the ionic app. Now I want to create my entities, I've done it on the backend part but when I do `yo jhipster-ionic:entity <myEntity>`, and select my backend I got this error :

> ERROR! Copying template ionic/src/pages/entities/_entity.html.ejs failed. [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\node_modules\generator-jhipster-ionic\generators\entity-client\templates\ionic\src\pages\entities_entity.html.ejs']

Comment: Which version of Jhipster and which version of jhipster-ionic module? I suspect you are mixing incompatible versions. You should report this on github with details at https://github.com/oktadeveloper/generator-jhipster-ionic/issues

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was : I was creating entity in the wrong folder.

I created my Ionic Application from a first folder. This creation made a second folder with the projet in it. And it was from the second folder than I needed to launch the entity creation.

(Also restarted my cmd, reinstalled jhipster-ionic but I don't think it has something to do with it)